# Can't close the Ouput Stream

Tags: java, oop

I am unable to compile the program. The problem is in the last line "out.close". Please tell me how to rectify it and why it is causing a problem.

```
import java.io.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        try {
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
            String line;
            line = in.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                out.write(line, 0, line.length());
                out.newLine();
                line = in.readLine();
            }
        } finally {
            out.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no `catch block`

Comment: thats not a problem try can work with finally also

Comment: Please use your IDE's "format" menu option, edit your question and paste the indented code. This is virtually unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare your `out` variable outside of yur `try . . . finally` block. Since `try` and `finally` are two different scopes, `out` is not defined in your `finally` block.

Answer (score 8):

You have to declare BufferedWriter out variable outside of try-finally block, because the variables declared in try block are out of scope in finally, it's called block scope. The code should be like:

```
BufferedWriter out = null;
try {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]));
    String line;
    line = in.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        out.write(line, 0, line.length());
        out.newLine();
        line = in.readLine();
    }
} finally {
    if (out != null)
        out.close();
}
```

Or as it's said in comments, if Java version is 7 or above, you should use try-with-resources:

```
try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[1]))) 
{
    String line;
    line = in.readLine();
    while (line != null) {
        out.write(line, 0, line.length());
        out.newLine();
        line = in.readLine();
    }
}
```

In that case, you don't need to close it manually in finally block.

Comment: Or using a try-with-resources block as of Java 7

Comment: If he's using Java 7+, he should also use a try-with-resources.

Comment: @gla3dr you beat me by three seconds!

Comment: In the first example, you should set `out` to `null`, otherwise it will generate a compilation error.

Comment: @Titus this behave from compiler, but yes, bettr to do it

Comment: In the first example, you should check if `out` isn't null before calling `close` on it.

Answer (score 2):

[Try with Resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (Java 7+). In this case, no need for close statements. Resources declared inside try will be auto closed.

```
    try(BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(args[1])))
        {
        String line;
        line = in.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            out.write(line, 0, line.length());
            out.newLine();
            line = in.readLine();
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    } catch (IOException e) {
    } finally {
    }
```